# How to make an infinite dimensional vector space complete?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

In the book Sadri Hassani, the author gave an example of a Cauchy series in which the vector at infinity does not lie in the original space. The example is shown below:-

[image: example]

He then goes on to define that the Hilbert space of square-integrable function is complete and isomorphic to Lebesgue spaces. However, he doesn't prove what you need in order to complete a vector space. For example, to complete rational numbers, you need real numbers.

My question is, given a vector space, is there a way to complete it in general. It would be extremely helpful if you can take the example mentioned and complete it if possible?

Comment: In more general, the same completion applies to any metric space: the elements of the completion are the Cauchy sequences, and two sequences are considered to be the same iff they would converge to the same limit point.

Comment: @Berci But there may be infinite Cauchy sequences in a vector space, if I am not wrong. How can you identify all those limit points?

Comment: It can also be done for $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb R$. A completion intuitively only 'fills the holes'. A rational number is represented specifically by a constant sequence, and $\sqrt2$ is represented by any sequence of rationals that converges to $\sqrt2$. Operations can be defined coordinatewise on any representations. The same goes for infinite dimensional topological vector spaces.